# Point arrays to same memory location

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have two structures, *which I cannot modify*, that are fairly similar, but not exactly the same. In the case of `struct1_t`, the first variable is an array of pointers to `tstStruct_t` structs. In the case of `struct2_t`, the first variable is simply an array of `tstStruct_t` structs.

My goal is to "link" these two structures together so that changes to `struct2` cause changes to `struct1` as well. The idea to accomplish this is to just point both of them at the same memory chunk. Assuming this approach is even viable, I can't seem figure out how to get this to work.

From my understanding, `struct1.var` is a pointer to the beginning of the chunk of memory containing four contiguous uint16_t's. So it makes sense that saying `struct1.var = struct2.var` will simply make `struct1.var` point to the same memory location as `struct2.var` and any changes to `struct2.var` will be seen by `struct1.var`. The same goes with `tst`, with the slight difference noted above.

*How can I accomplish this without doing a straight up memcpy* (for reasons I don't feel are necessary for this question)? Is it even possible to accomplish this?

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    uint16_t tst1;
    uint16_t tst2;
} tstStruct_t;

typedef struct {
    tstStruct_t (*tst)[4];
    uint16_t    var[4];
} struct1_t;

typedef struct {
    tstStruct_t tst[4];
    uint16_t    var[4];
} struct2_t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    struct1_t  struct1;
    struct2_t  struct2;

    memset(&struct2, 0, sizeof(struct2_t));

    // Print out tst1 from struct1
    printf("tst1: %d\n", struct1.tst[0]->tst1);

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        struct1.tst[i] = &(struct2.tst[i]); // WRONG!
    }
    struct1.var = struct2.var; // WRONG!

    struct2.tst[0].tst1 = 1;

    // Print out tst1 from struct1 again, expecting it to now be 1
    printf("frame1: %d\n", struct1.tst[0]->tst1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Arrays are not pointers.  Arrays decay to pointers under certain conditions. I.e.: `int arr[4];` is an array. `int *p = arr;` points to the first element of the array.

Comment: @TonyTheLion Then it seems I have a fundamental misunderstanding of arrays. Is my premise above completely flawed then and memcpy the only solution?

Comment: You can put pointers in the structs and have them point to the same location, which must be separately allocated.

Comment: As for the vars, you can make them pointers (not arrays) and have them point to a shared memory address. As fot he tst, it should work as far as I understand, but I'm not sure what this line does: `struct2.tst[0].1 = 1;`

Comment: @stark Unfortunately the format of my structs is not changeable. They have been given to me and are what I have to work with

Comment: @EladWeiss Good catch, that line does nothing because it was a typo. Fixed now. And as I said to stark, I have to work with the format of the structs as is.

Comment: I'm kinda guessing, but can you try to remove the () from `struct1.tst[i] = &(struct2.tst[i])`?

Comment: @EladWeiss That unfortunately still does not work. The `&` has a lower operator precedence than `.` and `[ ]` so technically the `( )` are not necessary, I just like to add them to remind myself what I'm getting the address of.

Comment: `struct1_t` and `struct2_t` can _not_ be overlapped. Doing `sizeof(...)` will show they have different sizes. In `struct1_t`, `tst` is an array of 4 `tstStruct_t`'s. In `struct2_t`, `tst` is a _pointer_ to an array of `tstStruct_t`'s of fixed length 4. To link them, you'd have to have the pointers in `struct2_t` point to the elements in `struct1_t`

Comment: @CraigEstey You basically just repeated the content of my question to me. What I'm trying to figure out is how to properly do this! My implementation above is definitely not the correct way.

Comment: After reviewing your question again, I have made changes to the answer I provided. Please review and provide a comment to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that I think will work. It compiles but I haven't tried to run it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    uint16_t tst1;
    uint16_t tst2;
} tstStruct_t;

typedef struct {
    tstStruct_t (*tst)[4];
    uint16_t    var[4];
} struct1_t;

typedef struct {
    tstStruct_t tst[4];
    uint16_t    var[4];
} struct2_t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    tstStruct_t mytst[4];
    struct1_t  struct1;
    struct2_t  struct2;

    memset(&struct2, 0, sizeof(struct2_t));

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        mytst[i].tst1 = i + 23;
        mytst[i].tst2 = i + 37;
    }

    struct1.tst = &mytst;

    // Print out tst1 from struct1
    printf("tst1: %d\n", struct1.tst[0]->tst1);

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        struct2.tst[i] = mytst[i];
    }

    struct1.tst = &struct2.tst;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        struct1.var[i] = struct2.var[i];
    }

    struct2.tst[0].tst1 = 1;

    // Print out tst1 from struct1 again, expecting it to now be 1
    printf("frame1: %d\n", struct1.tst[0]->tst1);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> This is definitely a helpful start. However your line struct1.var[i] = struct2.var[i] is basically a memcpy, which I'm trying to avoid.

`var` is an array of *scalars* so some copying is unavoidable. Per my earlier comments about `sizeof` being different, it can't be done in a single operation.

From your original post:

> From my understanding, `struct1.var` is a pointer to the beginning of the chunk of memory containing four contiguous uint16_t's

No, it's *not* a *pointer* to a chunk of memory. It *is* that chunk of memory. To be a pointer, it would need to be either `uint16_t *var` or [closer to what you're doing] `uint16_t (*var)[4]`

That's why manual copying is required.

`memcpy` *could* be used for the `var` array but it's [probably] not much faster for such a short loop [which would probably get unrolled].

And, `struct1.var = struct2.var` does *not* compile.

Note that `struct1.tst = &struct2.tst` avoids copying the array *contents* (i.e. it's just a pointer setup).

To do much better would require rearchitecting the structs [which you mentioned you can't do]. Something like moving `var` from `struct1_t/struct2_t` into `tstStruct_t` as a *scalar* (e.g. `uint16_t var`)

*Side note:* I've been programming in C for 35+ years and I've never [hardly ever] encountered the `type (*sym)[4]` syntax except for classroom(?) exercises posted on SO. IMO, It's cumbersome relative to the benefit it might provide. IIRC, the only other place I've seen it used [as a trick] is the `GMP` math library.

Comment: This is definitely a helpful start. However your line `struct1.var[i] = struct2.var[i]` is basically a memcpy, which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

The way that your question is worded is a bit confusing however after reading it over a couple of times I think I understand what you are wanting to do.

The following provides a technique that you could use. Since I am not sure as to your actual application it is difficult for me to decide if this approach will actually work for you. So if you could provide some feedback as a comment, I would appreciate it.

In addition I have added an update for using a proxy object that maps one of the two types of structs, `struct1_t` or `struct2_t` to a normalizing struct, `struct1_2_t` which is then used to access the actual object. This approach requires a new struct along with two mapping routines that will map an object of one of the two types to the proxy object. See **An Alternative - Using a Proxy Object** below.

What you want to do is to have a `union` of these two structs however the problem is that one `struct` has an array of `tstStruct_t tst[4]` while the other struct has a single pointer variable `tstStruct_t (*tst)[4]`. So the sizes of the two structs are not the same and the second member of the structs, `uint16_t    var[4]` have different offsets.

However if we want to we could pick the larger `struct` for holding our data, `struct2_t` and then access it through a properly initialized `struct1_t` variable by using preprocessor macros to do a bit of pointer arithmetic.

The down side of this approach is that in order to access the memory area through a `struct1_t` you will need to use the appropriate macros. You will also be wasting some space as the `var` array of a `struct1_t` will not be used.

The two macros will use a pointer to a `struct1_t` and to the necessary calculations to access the proper area. `TST_PTR()` is to access the `.tst1` and `.tst2` members of `struct2_t` and `VAR_PTR()` is to access the `.var` array. These macros also assume that there will not be any kind of unusual packing of the data members of the structs

```
#define TST_PTR(p,i)  (*(*((p)->tst) + i))
#define VAR_PTR(p,i)  *((uint16_t *)(*((p)->tst) + 4)+i)
```

Here is a test program that runs under Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition as C source code. What we do is to use the `struct2_t` to create a memory area that we then point the `tst` member of a `struct1_t` so that two variables of both types are pointing to the same area of memory. Any accessing through the `struct1_t` view is done with the macros.

So we duplicate your `struct` definitions as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    uint16_t tst1;
    uint16_t tst2;
} tstStruct_t;

typedef struct {
    tstStruct_t (*tst)[4];    // tst is a pointer to an array size of 4 elements
    uint16_t    var[4];
} struct1_t;

typedef struct {
    tstStruct_t tst[4];       // tst is an array of size of 4 elements
    uint16_t    var[4];
} struct2_t;
```

we can then write a test program as follows:

```
#define TST_PTR(p,i)  (*(*((p)->tst) + i))
#define VAR_PTR(p,i)  *((uint16_t *)(*((p)->tst) + 4)+i)

void printStructs(struct1_t struct1, struct2_t struct2)
{
    // get a copy of the pointer to the data area so that we can print
    // out the data stored there. 
    int i;
    printf(" Structs\n");

    // Print out struct1 view of memory area
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("  struct1 tst: i = %d   %d  %d\n", i, TST_PTR(&struct1, i).tst1, TST_PTR(&struct1, i).tst2);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("  struct1 var: i = %d   %d \n", i, VAR_PTR(&struct1,i));
    }

    printf("\n");

    // Print out struct2 view of memory area
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("  struct2 tst : i = %d   %d   %d\n", i, struct2.tst[i].tst1, struct2.tst[i].tst2);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("  struct2 var: i = %d   %d \n", i, struct2.var[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    struct2_t  struct2 = { 0 };
    struct1_t  struct1 = { &struct2.tst, 0 };    // point struct1.tst to struct2.tst so both are using the same memory area.

    // initialize our struct2 for our explorations to follow.
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        struct2.tst[i].tst1 = 10 + i;
        struct2.tst[i].tst2 = 100 + i;
        struct2.var[i] = i + 1000;
    }

    printStructs(struct1, struct2);  // test print

    // modify the area by accessing it through struct1.tst this time.
    // we are using a temporary pointer in order to work around Visual Studio 2013
    // which doesn't seem to like what we are doing here.
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        TST_PTR(&struct1, i).tst1 *= 2;
        TST_PTR(&struct1, i).tst2 *= 12;
        VAR_PTR(&struct1, i) += 120;
    }

    printStructs(struct1, struct2);

    return 0;
}
```

This new version does not issue any warnings in Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.

This sample program gives us the output of

```
Structs
  struct1 tst: i = 0   10  100
  struct1 tst: i = 1   11  101
  struct1 tst: i = 2   12  102
  struct1 tst: i = 3   13  103
  struct1 var: i = 0   1000
  struct1 var: i = 1   1001
  struct1 var: i = 2   1002
  struct1 var: i = 3   1003

  struct2 tst : i = 0   10   100
  struct2 tst : i = 1   11   101
  struct2 tst : i = 2   12   102
  struct2 tst : i = 3   13   103
  struct2 var: i = 0   1000
  struct2 var: i = 1   1001
  struct2 var: i = 2   1002
  struct2 var: i = 3   1003

 Structs
  struct1 tst: i = 0   20  1200
  struct1 tst: i = 1   22  1212
  struct1 tst: i = 2   24  1224
  struct1 tst: i = 3   26  1236
  struct1 var: i = 0   1120
  struct1 var: i = 1   1121
  struct1 var: i = 2   1122
  struct1 var: i = 3   1123

  struct2 tst : i = 0   20   1200
  struct2 tst : i = 1   22   1212
  struct2 tst : i = 2   24   1224
  struct2 tst : i = 3   26   1236
  struct2 var: i = 0   1120
  struct2 var: i = 1   1121
  struct2 var: i = 2   1122
  struct2 var: i = 3   1123
```

**An Alternative - Using a Proxy Object**

If we introduce a proxy object along with two routines to map each of the types, `struct1_t` and `struct2_t` to the proxy object, we can then access either type of `struct1_t` or `struct2_t` by using the proxy object.

The proxy object structure and the map routines would be as follows.

```
typedef struct {
    tstStruct_t *tst;
    uint16_t    *var;
} struct1_2_t;

struct1_2_t mapStruct1_to_1_2(struct1_t *p)
{
    struct1_2_t x = { 0 };

    x.tst = *(p->tst);
    x.var = p->var;

    return x;
}

struct1_2_t mapStruct2_to_1_2(struct2_t *p)
{
    struct1_2_t x = { 0 };

    x.tst = p->tst;
    x.var = p->var;

    return x;
}
```

The proxy object and the mapping functions can be used as demonstrated in the following code. The following functions are:

- two print functions to print out a test object via the struct and the proxy
- an update function that uses a proxy to accept either kind of test object

The source code is as follows.

```
void printStructs1(struct1_t struct1, struct1_2_t struct1_2)
{
    int i;
    printf("  Structs\n");
    // Print out struct1
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        tstStruct_t *p = struct1.tst;    // generates warning C4047: 'initializing' : 'tstStruct_t *' differs in levels of indirection from 'tstStruct_t (*)[4]'
        printf("    struct1: i = %d   %d  %d\n", i, p[i].tst1, p[i].tst2);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("    struct1 var: i = %d   %d \n", i, struct1.var[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    // Print out struct1_2
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("    struct1_2: i = %d   %d   %d\n", i, struct1_2.tst[i].tst1, struct1_2.tst[i].tst2);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("    struct1_2 var: i = %d   %d \n", i, struct1_2.var[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

void printStructs2(struct2_t struct2, struct1_2_t struct1_2)
{
    int i;
    printf("  Structs\n");
    // Print out struct2
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("    struct2: i = %d   %d   %d\n", i, struct2.tst[i].tst1, struct2.tst[i].tst2);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("    struct2 var: i = %d   %d \n", i, struct2.var[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    // Print out struct1_2
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("    struct1_2: i = %d   %d   %d\n", i, struct1_2.tst[i].tst1, struct1_2.tst[i].tst2);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("    struct1_2 var: i = %d   %d \n", i, struct1_2.var[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

// a simple update function to update a test object through its proxy object.
void updateStructs1(struct1_2_t *struct1_2)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        struct1_2->tst[i].tst1 -= 30;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    tstStruct_t xtst[4];
    struct1_t  struct1 = { &xtst, 0 };
    struct1_2_t struct1_2_1 = mapStruct1_to_1_2(&struct1);    // map the struct1 object to our struct1_2 proxy object
    struct2_t  struct2 = { 0 };
    struct1_2_t struct1_2_2 = mapStruct2_to_1_2(&struct2);    // map the struct2 object to our struct1_2 proxy object

    // initialize our struct1 object for our explorations to follow.
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        tstStruct_t *p = struct1.tst;    // generates warning C4047: 'initializing' : 'tstStruct_t *' differs in levels of indirection from 'tstStruct_t (*)[4]'
        p[i].tst1 = 50 + i;
        p[i].tst2 = 500 + i;
        struct1.var[i] = i + 5000;
    }

    // initialize our struct2 object for our explorations to follow.
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        struct2.tst[i].tst1 = 10 + i;
        struct2.tst[i].tst2 = 100 + i;
        struct2.var[i] = i + 1000;
    }

    printf("Step 1 printStructs1(struct1, struct1_2_1). Are they the same?\n");
    printStructs1(struct1, struct1_2_1);
    printf("Step 2 printStructs2(struct2, struct1_2_2). Are they the same?\n");
    printStructs2(struct2, struct1_2_2);

    // modify the struct1 data using the struct1_2x proxy.
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        struct1_2_1.tst[i].tst1 *= 2;
        struct1_2_1.tst[i].tst2 *= 12;
        struct1_2_1.var[i] += 120;
    }

    printf("Step 3 printStructs1(struct1, struct1_2_1). Are they the same?\n");
    printStructs1(struct1, struct1_2_1);

    // modify the struct2 data using the struct1_2 proxy.
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        struct1_2_2.tst[i].tst1 *= 3;
        struct1_2_2.tst[i].tst2 *= 14;
        struct1_2_2.var[i] += 150;
    }

    printf("Step 4 printStructs2(struct2, struct1_2_2). Are they the same?\n");
    printStructs2(struct2, struct1_2_2);

    updateStructs1(&struct1_2_1);
    printf("Step 5 printStructs1(struct1, struct1_2_1). Are they the same?\n");
    printStructs1(struct1, struct1_2_1);

    updateStructs1(&struct1_2_2);
    printf("Step 6 printStructs2(struct2, struct1_2_2). Are they the same?\n");
    printStructs2(struct2, struct1_2_2);

    return 0;
}
```